# How to add quotation marks to strings inside a string list?

Tags: python, regex, string

The idea is to add quotation marks for all strings inside an string list.

Tried the next:

```
import re

input_str='[abc, bca]'
output_str=re.sub(r',(\w*)', r',"\1"', input_str)

print(output_str)
```

Whcih returns:

```
# [abc,"" bca]
```

Expected Output could look like this:

```
# ["abc", "bca"]
```

Is it possible to adjust this regex in order to get desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match after both commas and open brackets, and you want to preserve spacing, so you need to allow for and capture the stuff to preserve so it can be reused. You also want to use `+` for your `\w` quantifier, as `\w*` will match *between* characters.

An updated regex might look like:

```
import re

input_str='[abc, bca]'
output_str=re.sub(r'([\[,])(\s*)(\w+)', r'\1\2"\3"', input_str)
                  # ^^^^^^^ Matches and captures open bracket or comma
                  #        ^^^^^ Matches and captures any spaces after bracket/comma
                  #             ^^^^^ Matches and captures at least one word character
print(output_str)
```

At the expense of using more complicated constructs (making the regex less portable to other regex syntaxes), you could avoid some of the captures using lookaround assertions that assert the presence of characters without including them in the string being replaced:

```
output_str=re.sub(r'(?<=[\[,])(\s*)(\w+)', r'\1"\2"', input_str)
```

where the fixed width pattern describing the bracket or comma is done with a lookbehind assertion, excluding it from the match and avoiding the need to include it in the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code:

```sh
import re

input_str='[abc, bca]'
print (['"' + s + '"' for s in re.findall(r'\w+(?=[,\]])', input_str)])
```

**output:**

```
['"abc"', '"bca"']
```

This code uses a regex `\w+(?=[,\]])` for matching. This regex matches a word if it is followed by a comma or `]`.

`for` loop loops through array returned from `findall` and wraps each element with `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to match on braces and commas, just use `re.sub` to find all words, and replace them with the word in quotes:

```
import re

input_str='[abc, bca]'
re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'"\1"', input_str)
# '["abc", "bca"]'
```

If you want an actual python `list`, then you can wrap this in the `json` parser:

```
import json
json.loads(re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'"\1"', input_str))
```

Comment: Assuming the input never contains strings *outside* a `list` which should not be quoted, this will work, but it will fail if run on a string like `mylist = [abc, bca]'` where only the contents of the quasi-`list` should be quoted, not `mylist`.

Comment: This answer fits within the scope of the question, and avoids any premature optimisation.

Comment: I wouldn't call it premature *optimization* to limit the scope to what's described, but yeah, I wasn't saying your answer was bad, just potentially a problem given the textual description of the problem (it obviously works fine for the example input).